# What's the best way to return an Enumerator::Lazy when your class doesn't define #each?

Tags: ruby, lazy-evaluation, enumerable, ruby-2.0

`Enumerable#lazy` relies on your enumerable providing an `#each` method. If your enumerable doesn't have an `#each` method you can't use `#lazy`. Now `Kernel#enum_for` and `#to_enum` provide the flexibility to specify an enumeration method other than `#each`:

```
Kernel#enum_for(method = :each, *args)
```

But `#enum_for` and friends always construct plain (non-lazy) enumerators, never `Enumerator::Lazy`.

I see that `Enumerator` in Ruby 1.9.3 offers this similar form of #new:

```
Enumerator#new(obj, method = :each, *args)
```

Unfortunately that constructor has been completely removed in Ruby 2.0. Also I don't think it was ever available at all on `Enumerator::Lazy`. So it seems to me that if I have a class with a method I want to return a lazy enumerator for, if that class has no `#each` then I have to define some helper class that does define `#each`.

For instance, I've got a `Calendar` class. It doesn't really make sense for me to offer to enumerate every date from the beginning of all time. An `#each` would be useless. Instead I offer a method that enumerates (lazily) from a starting date:

```
  class Calendar
    ...
    def each_from(first)
      if block_given?
        loop do
          yield first if include?(first)
          first += step
        end
      else
        EachFrom.new(self, first).lazy
      end
    end
  end
```

And that `EachFrom` class looks like this:

```
class EachFrom
  include Enumerable
  def initialize(cal, first)
    @cal   = cal
    @first = first
  end
  def each
    @cal.each_from(@first) do |yielder, *vals|
      yield yielder, *vals
    end
  end
end
```

It works but it feels heavy. Maybe I should subclass `Enumerator::Lazy` and define a constructor like that deprecated one from `Enumerator`. What do you think?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should return a normal `Enumerator` using `to_enum`:

```
class Calendar
  # ...
  def each_from(first)
    return to_enum(:each_from, first) unless block_given?
    loop do
      yield first if include?(first)
      first += step
    end
  end
end
```

This is what most rubyists would expect. Even though it's an infinite `Enumerable`, it is still usable, for example:

```
Calendar.new.each_from(1.year.from_now).first(10) # => [...first ten dates...]
```

If they actually need a lazy enumerator, they can call `lazy` themselves:

```
Calendar.new.each_from(1.year.from_now)
  .lazy
  .map{...}
  .take_while{...}
```

If you *really* want to return a lazy enumerator, you can call `lazy` from you method:

```
  # ...
  def each_from(first)
    return to_enum(:each_from, first).lazy unless block_given?
    #...
```

I would not recommend it though, since it would be unexpected (IMO), could be an overkill and will be less performant.

Finally, there are a couple of misconceptions in your question:

- All methods of `Enumerable` assume an `each`, not just `lazy`.
- You can define an `each` method that requires a parameter if you like and include `Enumerable`. Most methods of `Enumerable` won't work, but `each_with_index` and a couple of others will forward arguments so these would be usable immediately.
- The `Enumerator.new` without a block is gone because `to_enum` is what one should use. Note that the block form remains. There's also a constructor for `Lazy`, but it's meant to start from an existing `Enumerable`.
- You state that `to_enum` never creates a lazy enumerator, but that's not entirely true. `Enumerator::Lazy#to_enum` is specialized to return a lazy enumerator. Any user method on `Enumerable` that calls `to_enum` will keep a lazy enumerator lazy.

Comment: You just blew my mind Marc-André. My code just went from idiotic to idiomatic. I did not understand that Ruby wants us to always traffic in Enumerators and not Enumerator::Lazy. Wherever we need something to be lazy we ask that enumerator for the #lazy version. The downside perhaps is that users of our abstractions really have to understand when to call #lazy (e.g. before calling #drop(n)). The upside is crisp clean code.

Comment: I've had so much trouble with (and learned so much from) #drop(n). Now that I'm returning "plain" Enumerators everywhere I had to sprinkle a few ...lazy.drop(n)... about. So I defined a drop-like method that simply advances the Enumerator, letting me change those to ...skip(n)...

Comment: Right. You can definitely define a method like `Enumerable#skip(n)` that would return an `Enumerator` instead of an array like `drop` does and play with that.

Comment: In your third bullet above you say "the Enumerator constructor is not gone…" I was pointing out that the non-block form is gone (the one that lets you specify an enumeration method other than #each). Thanks again for showing me the way Marc-André!